# Number of ties repetition among vertices

Tags: r, weighted-graph

I have an undirected graph with 343 nodes and 4000+ edges. These nodes are connected to each other by different type of ties. Imagine I have A, B, C, D, E as nodes and tie 1, tie 2, and tie 3. I have organized my dataframe as below:

```
Column1    Column2    Column3
node1      node2      tie

A          C          1
C          A          3
D          A          2
B          A          2
A          B          1
```

As the example above can show, A and C and A and B have been linked with each other twice, regardless of their tie and whether they belong to "node1" or "node2" column. And the sum of these repetitions for the whole network is 4.

I exactly want to get this sum for my graph with 4000+ edges. Also would be cool to see the number of repeated links for a specific node/pair of nodes. Hope I make sense

Any help truly appreciated.

Comment: What are you using to process your graphs?  igraph?

Comment: simply reading it from excel!